# Verificar si un campo esta vació antes de insertarlo con PHP

Tags: php

Quiero insertar datos en mi BD, pero antes quiero comprobar con unos **if** si el campo está vació, si lo está quiero sustituirlo; cambiar : `''` por `null`, pero no lo hace, lo sigue dejando como un **string vacio** o sea asi: `''`.

Llega esto del form :

```
$fecha_nacimiento= $_POST['fecha_nacimiento'];
```

Entonces hago lo siguiente :

```
        if (strlen(trim($fecha_nacimiento)) == 0) {
            $fecha_nacimiento = null;   
        }
```

Haciendo un `echo` de `strlen(trim($fecha_nacimiento))` muestra `0`. Pero no pasa por el `if` que he puesto.

Esto lo quiero hacer porque tengo una variable `$sql` con el insert, y si pasa por el if lo ponga a null y si no lo que reciba.

Las fechas las recibo de un `input` de **tipo** : `date`.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO familiares(fecha_nacimiento) VALUES('".$fecha_nacimiento ."');";
```

La cosa es que da error si inserto un string sin formato **DATE** en la BD. Por lo que he querido controlar con un if que me diga, si es (`.length == 0`) que lo ponga a `null`. Pero no lo hace.

**ACLARACION** : El error no es que ponga `'NULL'` en vez de `NULL` y lo detecte como string, sino que el `var_dump()` (sea `.length == 0` o no) devuelve siempre `''`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El `if` que has planteado funciona correctamente. Con una cadena vacía la variable `$fecha_nacimiento` va a pasar a valer `NULL`.

El problema lo tienes en otro lado. Más concretamente en el `insert`:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO familiares(fecha_nacimiento) VALUES('".$fecha_nacimiento ."');";
```

Cuando tratas de imprimir el valor de una variable cuyo valor es `NULL` no vas a conseguir la palabra `NULL`, puesto que las variables de este tipo no tienen conversión a `string`, como también ocurre con las variables de tipo `boolean`, por lo que tu `insert` realmente está haciendo:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO familiares(fecha_nacimiento) VALUES("");";
```

Sin ver el resto de tu código, una posible solución sería el uso de [sentencias preparadas](https://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), que te permitirían pasarle a la `querie` una variable con valor `NULL` y además consigues hacer más segura tu aplicación al controlar la inyección SQL.

Answer (score 0):

No veo manera que falle el `if`; a menos que sea un caracter especial, lo cual podrías comprobar con `mb_strlen`. Tal vez el problema está en el manejo posterior.

Las reglas son: `trim(null) = ''` y `isset('') = true`.

Por lo tanto: `isset(trim(null)) = true`.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO familiares(fecha_nacimiento) VALUES("
     . ( isset($fecha_nacimiento) && $fecha_nacimiento != '' 
       ? sprintf("'%s'", $fecha_nacimiento)
       : 'null'
       )
     . ")";
```

Answer (score 0):

Hago la pregunta:
¿Eso lo haces para que en tu tabla los campos nulos se vean así?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

porque eso se logra poniendo por defecto NULL en el campo

```
`name` VARCHAR(191) DEFAULT NULL;
```